# Why is BizTalk Admin Console erroring about "Unable to access Rule Store Provider. Verify is Business Rule Engine Feature is installed and configured"

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

Recently I have been tasked to downgrade our BizTalk Non Production environment as it was running on BizTalk 2016 enterprise. After all the backups I then uninstalled BizTalk 2016 enterprise and installed Biztalk 2016 developer edition I then configured the BizTalk server to join the existing BizTalk databases for the Group and features such as SSO and Business Rules engine and finally I restored the master secret. I made sure that these features were part of the installation.

After that I opened the console everything seems to be in order except for when I import/export a policy

[image: Policy import/export error]

adding a policy

[image]

I restarted all the services I could think of, rule engine service, WMI, DTC, the server itself to no avail. I even checked the Business Rules Composer and I could see all our policies/vocabularies. I checked the Registry and I could see BizTalk and BusinessRules entries and couldnt find anything different from a working environment(the one I have not touched yet)

So here I am wondering if anyone have encountered this issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: Have a look at this blog.  Not the same error, but does show you a few things to check  https://manishrules.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/business-rule-composer-error-in-the-configuration-of-bre/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in this blog post that Colin Dijkgraaf have commented -
[manishrules.wordpress.com](https://manishrules.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/business-rule-composer-error-in-the-configuration-of-bre/)

Root cause
The table dbo.adm_Group in the BiztalkMgmtDb - somehow the values for RuleEngineDBServerName and RuleEngineDBName disappeared when I uninstalled the BizTalk Runtime for the downgrade, even worse the DateModified column didnt get changed.

Fix
I inserted the values for the columns mentioned and its now fixed

Comment: Don't forget to use the green tick to accept your own answer.